# Form в php или отправка методом get

Tags: php, post, get

имею код

```
$return['form' ] = array(
        "action" => "//www.free-kassa.ru/merchant/cash.php",
        "hidden" => array(
            "m" => $shop_id,
            "oa" => $price,
            "o" => $orderid,
            "s" => $sign,
            "i" => "",
            "lang" => "ru",
            "em" => "",
        )
```

но по умолчанию , почему то генерирует post запрос , а мне нужен get, , везде пошарился по файлам , где он мог задаваться , ничего не нашел , кто что подскажет ?
генерирует он следующие

```
<form action="//www.free-kassa.ru/merchant/cash.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="m" value="***">
<input type="hidden" name="oa" value="**">
<input type="hidden" name="o" value="***">
<input type="hidden" name="s" value="*********">
<input type="hidden" name="i" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="lang" value="ru">
<input type="hidden" name="em" value="">
<input type="submit" class="com-link" value="Продолжить"></form>
```

Comment: Найдите код, который генерирует HTML-форму из вашего массива. Найдите в этом коде, как должен выставляться method.

Comment: прикол в том , что это dle , в html по умолчанию method GET

Answer (score 1):

Замените method post на get в форме:

```
<form action="//www.free-kassa.ru/merchant/cash.php" method="get">
```

тогда следуя логики:

```
$return['form' ] = array(
        "action" => "//www.free-kassa.ru/merchant/cash.php",
        "method" => 'GET',
        "hidden" => array(
            "m" => $shop_id,
            "oa" => $price,
            "o" => $orderid,
            "s" => $sign,
            "i" => "",
            "lang" => "ru",
            "em" => "",
        )
```

Comment: у него нет готового html. он генерирует его. где-то у него там в пыхыпы надо смотреть настройку, как написал мелкий в комментарии

Comment: следуя логике то конечно да , НО , я уже пытался ставить 
"method" => 'GET', ему вообще побоку на моё действие :D

Comment: @Gam-Studio зайдём с другой стороны что это за фреймворк, что за метод вызываеться от какого наследуеться. Что в нутри родительского метода?\

Answer (score 1):

решил проблему правками конфига php